# Simple Python Blur Convolution Kernel Function Generates Weird Image

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, machine-learning, convolution

I was writing a custom function to apply a blur to an image using a convolution kernel. When I show the image, however, there is a weird result. In some ways is seems that the image was inverted, but I am not sure why. Here is the original image:

[image: Original Image]

Here is the result:

[image]

I have already tried re writing the code, changing the image, changing the blur kernel, printing and personally going through many convolutions by eye, etc.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def showImage(image):
    plt.imshow(image, cmap='gray')
    plt.show()


def gaussianBlur(image):
    tempImage = image.copy()
    tempImage = np.pad(tempImage, 1, "constant")

    showImage(tempImage)
    max = 0
    i = 0
    for x in range(1, len(image)-1):
        for y in range(1, len(image[0])-1):
            roi = image[x-1:x+2, y-1:y+2]
            kernel = np.array([
                [0.0625, 0.125, 0.0625],
                [0.125, 0.25, 0.125],
                [0.0625, 0.125, 0.0625]
            ])

            if np.matmul(roi, kernel).sum() > max:
                max = np.matmul(roi, kernel).sum()
            tempImage[x][y] = np.matmul(roi, kernel).sum()

            i += 1

            print(np.matmul(roi, kernel).sum())
            # if(i % 1000 == 0):
            #     showImage(tempImage)

    divAmount = max / 255

    for x in range(1, len(image)-1):
            for y in range(1, len(image[0])-1):
                tempImage[x][y] = tempImage[x][y] / divAmount
    return tempImage.tolist()

# Load and view the image
image = cv2.imread("image_1_small.jpg", 0)
showImage(image)

# Apply Blur
image = gaussianBlur(image)
print(image)
# image = cv2.GaussianBlur(image, (5, 5), 0)
showImage(image)
```

The expected outcome should look like the original image only blurred.

Comment: Is there any reason you do not use [cv2.filter2D](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html#filter2d)?

Comment: I wanted to make it myself. I can do that as an alternative however.

Comment: Its recommended to avoid loops, because they are not efficient at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is caused by overflows. You compute convolution wrong. Use np.multiply in place of np.matmul.

Comment: @BrandonFeder, It worked for me. Have you replaced all instances of np.matmul with np.multiply?

Comment: Ok. I replaced all of them. I missed one and it works! Thanks.